# C++ error when using GLFW calls

Tags: c++, glfw

I've been learning to program in c++ recently, but I've run into a problem when using GLEW and GLFW.

Source (.cpp):

```
#include<iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GLEW/glew.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"test";

    GLFWWindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"Test", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(),NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles with no errors, but when it is run, no output is generated despite the std::cout. However, as soon as the glfwCreateWindow call is commented out, the program shows the output it should.

I'm extremely confused by this and would like to know if there's anything I can do to fix it.

EDIT: I doubt it's a problem with std::cout, because when I try showing the window like so, I still get no response from the program.

```
glfwShowWindow(window);
while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))glfwPollEvents();
glfwDestroyWindow(window);
```

EDIT 2: 
Here is my code as of now:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include "GLEW/glew.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"test" << std::endl;
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"TEST", NULL, NULL);

    glfwShowWindow(window);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))glfwPollEvents();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    std::cin.get();
}
```

EDIT 3: Title

EDIT 4: After some experimentation, I've found that any mention of a glfw call in the source file seems to prevent the program from running. The following generates no output:

```
int main(){
    std::cout<<"test" << std::endl;

    std::cout.flush();

    std::cin.get();
}
void test(){
    glfwInit();

    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow(800,600,"TEST", NULL, NULL);

    glfwShowWindow(window);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))glfwPollEvents();
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();

}
```

Comment: Redirect your program output into a file. It sounds like you're just having a misunderstanding with your terminal emulator, rather than with C++.

Comment: Try ending your output with a newline. You're probably just not noticing the output because it's on the same line as your prompt.

Comment: std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl; seems to make no difference. I have yet to try redirecting to a file.

Comment: Perhaps, call the necessary code to end `glfw` program: `glfwTerminate()`

Comment: @mr5 It seems the program doesn't even execute the main() method in the first place.

Comment: @user3780362 Why don't you write a valid `glfw` program to test that out then?

Comment: or try leaving the 4th parameter of `glfwCreateWindow` to `nullptr` and replace `return 0` with `std::cin.get()` and see what happens

Comment: @mr5 I was also missing a call to glfwInit() :P, but even with the changes, the program just doesn't output anything.

Comment: @user3780362 Could you update your post and include your code work so far? Or why don't you try the simplest valid example of a working glfw program in their [documentation](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html)?

Comment: Does a simple hello-world work for you? If not then how are you executing this program? Are you using commands or an executable or?

Comment: @user3780362 Have you considered checking the link I gave to you lately? Just copy paste it and insert your additional feature `std::cout << "test" << std::endl;`. Maybe there were build errors, and you didn't check what those functions were returning.

Comment: @Brandon I'm running this using MinGW and Eclipse

Comment: @mr5 a simple "hello world" works fine, it's just that the mention of a glfw call prevents any output from the program

Comment: @user3780362 Post the compilation command produced by your IDE. Since you do not get any output when not even calling any glfw function you may have a linker issue. I have not used eclipse so I do not know what it does when it have nothing to run.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons for no output on `stdout`:

- If you are running on Windows, your program may have been compiled within the windows subsystem. Then, any print to `stdout` will go to the bitbucket. If you are using the MinGW toolchain, this is controlled by the `-mwindows` linker flag
- If the program crashes, then buffered output may not be written. Therefore, try to flush your output stream before doing anything else. Note that programs may crash silently.

Some things you can ask to find out more:

- What happens when you step through your code with the debugger shipped with your compiler?
- Since `glfwCreateWindow` hid the output, maybe it crashes inside that function. Did you pass the correct arguments?
- Does `glfwCreateWindow` return a valid pointer?

Comment: I've made some edits that might give more insight into the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, looking at the documentation for glfwCreateWindow(), It is stated that you should only call glfwCreateWindow() in the main function.

[Documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344)

try to pass glfwCreateWindow as parameter to test()